# Asynchronous localization with custom resource storage in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, asynchronous, async-await, localization, asp.net-core-localization

I'm using custom storage for IStringLocalizer in .net core which has async method to get resources.
I'd like to have it async all the way long.
Here's snippet:

```
public class CustomStringLocalizer : IStringLocalizer
    {
        public LocalizedString this [string name]
        {
            get
            {
                var culture = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture;

                Task<string> translation = _customStorage.GetResource(culture, key, name).Result; //can't make it 'await'

                return new LocalizedString (name, translation, translation != null);
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I make the property async so I can use await for this method?
Getting result from the task gives also an error: One or more errors occurred. (The type 'Task`1' must be serializable)

Comment: `Task<string> translation = _customStorage.GetResource(culture, key, name).Result;`

It looks like this method's return type is `Task<Task<string>>` what seems a bug for me.

Comment: currently, it's not working so the question is how to get rid of getting "Result" from the task

Comment: "how to get rid of getting "Result" from the task"

I don't really understand this question. Also I don't know the `_customStorage`'s interface or implementation.

Comment: It returns Task<string>... Get rid means that I don't want to call for task's result as it eliminates the whole async idea.

Comment: You can't use async call in a non async context without using .Result or .GetAwaiter().GetResult() (these are more or less equal). Simply there is no way. You either make .GetResource(...) synchronous or you live with using .Result.

Maybe if you could preload the values on startup so you don't have to call .GetResource(...) every time?

Comment: there's caching inside getResources method so not a big deal for performance. Thank you for your help. I was hoping there some async usage of default .net core localization

Answer (score 0):

You can't make a property async. Use async method instead.

Comment: this property comes from the default localization interface which has to be implemented

Comment: Then I am afraid you have to use `.Result` in this case when calling `.GetResource`.